# TensorFlow train.Supervisor - save checkpoint upon training stop?

Tags: tensorflow, checkpointing

In TensorFlow 1.0, `tf.train.Supervisor` saves checkpoints at intervals of `save_model_secs`. Is there any way to save a checkpoint at the termination of training, rather than periodically during training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.train.Supervisor` writes a checkpoint at the end of looping. If you want to avoid writing other checkpoints, you can just set `save_model_secs` to a large value. Here is an example that just saves a single, final checkpoint:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y = tf.Variable(0)
y = tf.assign_add(y, 1)

sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir='/tmp', save_model_secs=100000000)

with sv.managed_session() as sess:

    for step in range(10):
        if sv.should_stop():
             break

        print(sess.run(y))
```